# IN statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Query 1:

```
DECLARE @strSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @MultiIDs NVARCHAR(50) = '7,8'
SET @strSQL = 'SELECT TOP 1 [User].PracticeID FROM [User] WHERE [UserId] IN (' + @MultiIDs + ')'    
EXEC(@strSQL)
```

Query2 :

```
DECLARE @MultiIDs NVARCHAR(550) = '7,8'
SELECT TOP 1 [User].PracticeID FROM [User] WHERE [UserId] IN (@MultiIDs)
```

Why Query1 will work not Query2?

any explanation is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Because query 2 results in

```
WHERE [UserId] IN ('7,8')
```

which is **one** string (containing 2 values) and not **separate** values.

Query 1 is completely a string and will be translated into

```
WHERE [UserId] IN (7,8)
```

(notice the quotes)

Comment: which should be same case in query 1? no?

Comment: No, query 1 is a string itself and will be translated into a query.

Comment: so according to your answer if I replace ' with empty it should work in the second query right?

Comment: You can't do that. Either put seperate values in there or use a dynamic query like you did in query 1